# Numerical solution of a PDE having boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, homework

I am solving a PDE using Mathematica. and I would like to know how to implement the condition that the three-variable function `u[t, x, z]`

```
A = 1.08152;  

B = 1.26415;

Cc = 431.188;

W = 0.0590505;

Phi = 1.590; 

eq = 
  {D[u[t, x, z], t] + A (u[t, x, z] D[u[t, x, z], z]) + B D[u[t, x, z], {z, 3}] + 
    B Cc D[D[u[t, x, z], {x, 2}], {z, 1}] == 0};
```

where `u[0, x, z] = Phi (Sec[x/W])^2`

I want to solve the PDE shown with `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue` and plot its 3D graph.

Comment: Have you tried looking through the documentation? Try https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveAPartialDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: @ZahidKumai Do you mean initial conditions `u[0,x,z]== Phi*(Sec[x/W])^2`?

Comment: Yes, its use in initial condition.

Comment: @ZahidKumail There were incorrect brackets with `D[]`. I edited, but not sure what is correct. Can you publish the equation in `TeX` form or give a link to the article where it is published?